# Syntax for if/else condition in SCSS mixin

Tags: conditional-statements, mixins, sass, if-statement

Hi I'm trying to learn SASS/SCSS and am trying to refactor my own mixin for clearfix

what I'd like is for the mixin to be based on whether I pass the mixin a width.

thoughts so far (pseudo code only as I will be including other mixins)

```sass
@mixin clearfix($width) {

   @if !$width {

    // if width is not passed, or empty do this

   } @else {

        display: inline-block;
        width: $width;
   }
}
```

here's how I thought I might call it, but it's not working.

`@include clearfix();`

or

`@include clearfix(100%)`

or

`@include clearfix(960px)`

I'd appreciate any help on the best or right way to do this!

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You could try this:

```sass
$width:auto;
@mixin clearfix($width) {

   @if $width == 'auto' {

    // if width is not passed, or empty do this

   } @else {
        display: inline-block;
        width: $width;
   }
}
```

I'm not sure of your intended result, but setting a default value should return false.

Comment: it does, thank you I had it using `" "` but I like the auto value better :) - didn't need to set variable though I put it in the mixin syntax as the default vaue `@mixin clearfix($width: auto) {...`  thank you :)

Comment: Is any purpose for giving $width:auto; as default value?

Answer (score 228):

You can assign default parameter values inline when you first create the mixin:

```sass
@mixin clearfix($width: 'auto') {

  @if $width == 'auto' {

    // if width is not passed, or empty do this

  } @else {

    display: inline-block;
    width: $width;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You could default the parameter to `null` or `false`.
This way, it would be shorter to test if a value has been passed as parameter.

```sass
@mixin clearfix($width: null) {

  @if not ($width) {

    // if width is not passed, or empty do this

  } @else {

    display: inline-block;
    width: $width;

  }
}
```