# Is it possible to test for the current element type from within a SASS mixin?

Tags: sass

I have a mixin that draws a button like this:

```
@mixin button {
  border: 1px solid $orange;
  background: $orange;
  padding:0;
  height:27px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color:white;
  display:block;
  // if I'm styling an a tag padding-top:10px 10px 0 10px;
}
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
button.my_button {
  @include button;
}

a.my_button {
  @include button;
}
```

The second one requires some additional custom code to work nicely. Is is possible to include a conditional in the mixin that checks to see if I'm styling an a tag, or do I need write a second mixin?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9488849/465082 You can use conditionals inside the `@mixin` block and call `@include button('link')` or `@include button(`tag`)

Comment: Could you explain exactly what's wrong with your code as is?

Comment: I have updated the question to make it clearer. The a tag needs additional styling to render like the button tag.

Comment: Hi Kashyap, that's a good solution, but I'd rather not have to pass the value, I'd rather it could just inspect the current context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Sass 3.3 and older

Within a mixin, no.  If you're open to extends, you can get pretty close:

```
$orange: lighten(orange, 10%);

%button {
  border: 1px solid $orange;
  background: $orange;
  padding:0;
  height:27px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color:white;
  display:block;
}

a%button {
    padding-top:10px 10px 0 10px;
}

button.my_button {
  @extend %button;
}

a.my_button {
  @extend %button;
}
```

Compiles to:

```
button.my_button, a.my_button {
  border: 1px solid #ffb733;
  background: #ffb733;
  padding: 0;
  height: 27px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

a.my_button {
  padding-top: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}
```

## Sass 3.4 and newer

Starting with 3.4 we have the ability to examine and manipulate the selector.

```
$orange: lighten(orange, 10%);

@mixin button {
  border: 1px solid $orange;
  background: $orange;
  padding:0;
  height:27px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color:white;
  display:block;

  @if is-superselector('a', &) {
    padding-top: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  }
}

button {
  @include button;
}

b a.foo {
  @include button;
}
```

Output:

```
button {
  border: 1px solid #ffb733;
  background: #ffb733;
  padding: 0;
  height: 27px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

b a.foo {
  border: 1px solid #ffb733;
  background: #ffb733;
  padding: 0;
  height: 27px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As of this writing, there's no way to inspect the context / element type in a conditional.  But you can set a default in your conditional, and thus simplify the default case of the mix-in.

Here's an example:

```
@mixin button($type: normal) { 

  border: 1px solid orange; background: orange; color: white; display: block;

    @if $type == anchor { padding: 10px 10px 0 10px; } 
    @else { padding: 0; }

}

button.my_button {
  @include button;
}

a.my_button {
  @include button($type: anchor);
}
```

See it in action at http://sassmeister.com/gist/6284603.

It looks like this functionality is (maybe) planned for Sass 3.3 with the `@at-root` directive: https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/774.

Comment: That's great, thanks Katie. Looks like it's currently not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use *@content* directive.

```
$orange: #000;
@mixin button {
    border: 1px solid $orange;
    background: $orange;
    padding: 0;
    height: 27px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    @content;
}
button.my_button {
    @include button;
}

a.my_button {
    @include button {
       padding-top:10px 10px 0 10px;
    };
}
```

Using this approach you will keep your mixin untouched and you will still have the functionality that you want.

Comment: There's not really a reason to use `@content` here since there's only 1 selector in use.  You're just as well off typing `a.my_button { @include button; padding-top: 10px 10px 0 10px; }`

Comment: It depends. I like the *@content* directive, because it gives you ability to keep the mixin untouched and still overwrite some of its styles. Also the syntax looks good.

Comment: While it works out to the same compiled CSS, there is no benefit to `@content` in this instance.  That's the point I'm trying to make here.  The `@content` directive is only useful in instances where you've got a selector being generated within the mixin.  Otherwise, you may as well not be using it at all and define the extra styles after your mixin call.

Answer (score 2):

There is a newer solution that even works in other systems outside of SASS:

#### `:is()`

```
&:is(a[href]) {
  // only links
}
```

https://caniuse.com/css-matches-pseudo