# Using if() css function to compare sizes with a unit

Tags: css, if-statement, sass, comparison, conditional-statements

I basically have a css variable `--my-variable` that contains something like `250px` (with the unit px).
I want to apply style based on the size contained in that variable.

For example:

`background-color: if( var(--my-variable) > 200px , green, red );`

Seems that I can't compare this way... What am I doing wrong ? Any idea ?

I am using SCSS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: css cannot do this, you need javascript for that.

Comment: you are using SCSS, Sass? if yes, take a look here, maybe it can help: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if

Comment: I think you have to use mixins. Try look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456467/syntax-for-if-else-condition-in-scss-mixin

Comment: Yeah I already looked these pages, doesn't help because I want to compare with ">", not an "=="

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to colour your content in a media query.
CSS calcs doesn't have an if statement.