# Check if color SASS is black, white or grey

Tags: css, sass

I'd like to check in SASS if a color is white, black, or a nuance of grey.

**Exemple :**

If color is red => apply my css
If color is "#000" or "#686868" => don't apply my css

Is there any solution using SASS or native CSS ?

Comment: This will help: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax for if/else condition in SCSS mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456467/syntax-for-if-else-condition-in-scss-mixin)

Comment: I am not quite sure how  to understand your question. Could you clarify it. Do you mean how to work in sass with `@if`? Do you mean how to check if a dynamic set color in browser is red/gray? Or do you mean how to compare colors in if-directive (i.e. something  `$color == '#000`? A code example would help in every case.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal yes, but i need something more, i don't want to use `@if` for all grey colors... there is a lot of hex codes for grey colors... Is there any solutions to test with a sass function or something more is a hex code is a grey color ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for clarification your question in comment.

**Indeed there is an easy possibility in SASS to check if color is a gray color**

**Use:** `@if $color == grayscale($color) { ... }`
See documentation: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#grayscale

If you want to wrap that in a function do:

```
@function is_gray($color){
    
    $result: false;
    @if $color == grayscale($color){
        $result: true;
    }
    @return $result;
}


// than call ...
@if is_gray($test){
   ...
}
```